# Trying to convert number string in date field of XML file to yy/mm/dd in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, date

I have some text messages saved from my Android (Galaxy S4) as XML files (UTC-8). I honestly don't know anything about XML, but I need to be able to reproduce these messages in a readable format for a legal matter. I can open them in Word or Excel without the tags, but I need to be able to convert the date field from a number string to dd/mm/yy.

Since some of the messages are saved as threads, there are multiple dates included within the same XML file, and I can't tell what they are. I tried using an XML conversion program, but the date field appeared the same way. Here is the beginning of one of the raw files, with personal info removed: (I tried to include the code tags by using the old html comment tag I'm familiar with to show the block as a comment, but it didn't work here)

***This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.***

file ver=2

thread n="292"

message type="SMS"

address 856XXXXXXX

body
Me+again.*text deleted*
end body

date 1431206949887

read 1

type 2

locked 0

end message

Is there an easy way to figure out what date 1431206949887 represents? Thanks so much!

Comment: Bingo! That is the one date in the file that I know is correct! Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

If Unix epoch time in milliseconds could be `19 May 2015 21:29:10 GMT`.

See [Excel 2013 Quick Tip: Convert Unix (Epoch) time in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WquZY9cwVjo).